(GODOT 4.3) how to make it so that the player that moves via tilemap move forever when an arrow key is pressed?
(ik i made a post similar to this, its just that i decided to switch to godot so i can make games more easier than in flash since its outdated)
i made a character that the player can control and it moves via tiles and tilemap, i wanna make it so that the player can move forever when an arrow key is pressed (and moving to the direction of said arrow key) until it goes into a walkable tile thats touching a non-walkable tile
you can give me any hints on how to do so, heres the code:
extends Sprite2D

class_name PacMan

@export var move_speed: float = 1



@onready var tile_map: TileMap = $"../TileMap"

@onready var sprite_2d: Sprite2D = $Sprite2D

@onready var animation_player: AnimationPlayer = $Sprite2D/AnimationPlayer


var is_moving = false

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    if is_moving == false:
        return
    if global_position == sprite_2d.global_position:
        is_moving = false
        return
    sprite_2d.global_position = sprite_2d.global_position.move_toward(global_position, move_speed)

func _ready() -> void:
    animation_player.play("chomping")

func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    if is_moving:
        return
    if Input.is_action_pressed("up"):
        rotation_degrees = 90
        move(Vector2.UP)
        is_moving = true
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("down"):
        rotation_degrees = 270
        move(Vector2.DOWN)
        is_moving = true
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        rotation_degrees = 0
        move(Vector2.LEFT)
        is_moving = true
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        rotation_degrees = 180
        move(Vector2.RIGHT)
        is_moving = true

func move(direction: Vector2):
    var current_tile: Vector2i = tile_map.local_to_map(global_position)
    var target_tile: Vector2i = Vector2i(
        current_tile.x + direction.x,
        current_tile.y + direction.y,
    )
    var tile_data: TileData = tile_map.get_cell_tile_data(0, target_tile)
    if tile_data.get_custom_data("walk_tiles") == false:
        return
    #Player movement
    is_moving = true
    global_position = tile_map.map_to_local(target_tile)
    sprite_2d.global_position = tile_map.map_to_local(current_tile)


Multiple possible solutions. My recommendation would be to create a global variable to store the current direction of the player. Then, instead of calling move(direction), change the player_direction variable and make a call to a direction-agnostic move() function.
Example semi-pseudocode:
var player_direction = Vector2.ZERO
func process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("up"):
        player_direction = Vector2.UP
    #etc. for the other directions
    
    move()

func move():
    #exactly as you have it, but using player_direction instead of direction


that looks nice

i tried the code and it works perfectly (the tile-based movement aswell) but i have a few problems, the player moves extremely fast and the player eases out when it stops moving (by ease out i mean it slowly slows down when it hits the last walkable tile instead of just stopping)

nvm i fixed it.
